# How can I tell when a process has finished writing to a file?

Tags: files, process, lock

I have a process which has been spawned from a shell. It is running as a background process and exporting a DB to a CSV file in `/tmp`.

How can I tell when the background process has completed (finished / quit) or if the CSV file lock has closed? I plan to FTP the file to another host once it's written, but I need the complete file before I start the file transfer.

Comment: Make the process inform you somehow...

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, the file is not locked even when a program is writing to it (unlike windows).

To check if the process is completed, use:

```
while [[ 1 ]]; do
  pgrep dbprocess &>/dev/null

  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo still running
  else
    echo finished
    # start ftp transfer
  fi
  sleep 2
done
```

To check if the process has the file open, you can use

- `lsof <file>` it will list the processes which opened `<file>`
- `ls -l /proc/$(pgrep db-process)/fd` lists the file descriptors open by the process `db-process`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `wait` shell built-in to accomplish this.

The `wait` builtin simply causes the shell to pause waiting for background jobs to complete. You can either pass it a specific job to wait for, or have it wait for all jobs.

For example:

```
echo $(date): starting
sleep 5 &
echo $(date): do something else
wait
echo $(date): background job finished
```

Which results in:

```
Thu Sep 25 12:06:48 EDT 2014: starting
Thu Sep 25 12:06:48 EDT 2014: do something else
Thu Sep 25 12:06:53 EDT 2014: background job finished
```